# Intermittent connection to Azure WebRole Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure, azure-web-roles

I'm having an issue with a webrole that contains multiple .aspx files that I use as an API to query the status of a service.

The service runs fine for a few hours, then one of the pages stops responding only on some connections intermittently. Just a few minutes ago, any connection to that single page was not responding from my home Wifi but returning just fine from my phone's cellular.

When I mean not responding, the browser just stalls (Waiting for response...). Wireshark tells me the server is indeed acknowledging the connection but IIS never returns anything, and there is no trace of the connection in the IIS log to that particular file.
Other aspx files work just fine in that time period with the same connection (I can see them in IIS Logs)

The page is querying a database using a Linq DataContext, but I don't think that's what's causing the problem since it wouldn't work with the phone as well.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.